# viewing and selecting subsets of many to many in admin

Tags: django

Here is my basic model:

```
Class Company(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    basic_contract = models.FileField(upload_to='company_forms')

Class Addendum(models.Model):
    attachment = models.FileField(upload_to='addendum_forms')
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)

Class Contract(models.Model):
    customer = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    attachments = models.ManyToManyField(Addendum)
```

This is my simplified model.  I have check boxes enabled in my admin module when selecting addendums to attach to a contract.  I would like my admin screen to filter out the addendums only applicable to the company selected on the contract.

When I use the django admin out of the box, I have a full list of my addendums.  Is there any way to immediately filter this based on company selection?  Is this possible considering that I have to select a company when creating a new contract?  What can be my possible solutions here?

Comment: exact duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630619/django-queryset-for-many-to-many-field

Comment: I'm not trying to do a query but to have the proper addendums view properly in the admin screen when adding a new contract.