# Django query for many-to-many subset containment

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, django-queryset, django-orm

Is there a way to query for subset or superset containment with many-to-many fields?

Suppose each Person has a list of birds they want to see, and each Aviary houses a list of birds.  How can I make a query to find, for a given Person instance, which Aviaries have *every bird* on the person's list?  And similarly, for a given Person instance, how do I find which Aviaries have *only* birds on the person's list (but not necessarily all of them).

Here are my Django 1.5 models:

```
class Bird(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class Aviary(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    birds = models.ManyToManyField(Bird)

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    birds_to_see = models.ManyToManyField(Bird)
```

I know how I would find the aviaries that have at least *one* of a person's birds, but I don't see how I would adapt that here.  (See, for instance:
[django queryset for many-to-many field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630619/django-queryset-for-many-to-many-field))

If there is a query that does what I want, I am also interested to know if/why it's preferable to doing this more "manually."  For example, I could loop over aviaries, extract each aviary's bird list, and see if the person's birds_to_see is a subset or superset of the aviary's bird list:

```
def find_aviaries(self):
    person_birds = set(self.birds_to_see.all())
    found_aviaries = []
    for aviary in Aviary.objects.all():
        aviary_birds = set(aviary.birds.all())
        if person_birds.issubset(aviary_birds):
            found_aviaries.append(aviary)            
    return found_aviaries
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

A nice solution exists for **Django >= 2.0**. It is possible to **annotate Aviaries by the number of matching  Birds** and to filter Aviaries that match at least one Bird or a required number.

```py
from django.db.models import Count

    ...
    person_birds = set(self.birds_to_see.all())
    aviaries = (
        Aviary.objects
        .annotate(bird_match_count=Count('birds', filter=Q(birds__in=person_birds)))
        .filter(bird_match_count__gt=0)
    )
```

It is then trivial to filter a new queryset by `bird_match_count=len(person_birds)` or to filter the original queryset in Python or to sort it by bird_match_count.

Django < 2.0 would require to reference the intermediary model `AviaryBirds` and will be more verbose.

---

**Verified** by reading the SQL:

```sql
>>> print(aviaries.query)
SELECT aviary.id, aviary.name,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN  aviary_birds.bird_id IN (1,..)  THEN aviary_birds.bird_id ELSE NULL END)
    AS bird_match_count
FROM aviary LEFT OUTER JOIN aviary_birds ON (aviary.id = aviary_birds.aviary_id)
GROUP BY aviary.id, aviary.name
HAVING
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (aviary_birds.bird_id IN (1,..)) THEN aviary_birds.bird_id ELSE NULL END)
     > 0
```

Comment: You should be able to reference `Aviary.birds.through` to get a reference to the "through" model in older versions of Django.

Comment: @MatthewSchinckel Yes. That I thought by the note about Django < 2.0, but I did not expect it so complicated as your solution with Postgres Subquery Array. I verify it maybe.

Answer (score 2):

Using a Postgres Subquery Array construct, you can annotate on the ids, and then filter accordingly:

```
birds = Aviary.birds.through.objects.filter(
    aviary=OuterRef('pk')
).values('bird')
aviaries = Aviary.objects.annotate(
    bird_ids=SubqueryArray(birds)
).filter(bird_ids__contains=target_bird_ids)
```

You can also use `__contained_by` to go the other way (or `__overlap` if you just want any match).

All you need then is a suitable `SubqueryArray` class:

```
class SubqueryArray(django.db.models.expressions.Subquery):
    template = 'ARRAY(%(subquery)s)'
    output_field = ArrayField(base_field=models.CharField())
```

You may need to adjust the output field on that, depending upon what your PK field is.

Comment: (Note for posterity: this solution did not exist at the time the original question was asked - that feature was not implemented until much later).