# Django filter where every item in an object's many to many list is included in provided queryset

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-queryset, django-orm, django-filter

I have the following models.

```
class Document(models.Model):
  allowed_groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, related_name='allowed_documents')

class Person(models.Model):
  permission_groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, related_name='people')

class Group(models.Model):
  id = models.BigIntegerField()
```

I want to find all the documents that Person can access with the condition that they have to be a member of all of the allowed groups.

I want this:
Case

1. Document(allowed_groups=1,2,7) with Person(permission_groups=1,2,6,7,11,15) -> MATCH
2. Document(allowed_groups=1,2,7) with Person(permission_groups=1,7) -> NO_MATCH
3. Document(allowed_groups=1,2,7) with Person(permission_groups=1,2) -> NO_MATCH
4. Document(allowed_groups=1,2,7) with Person(permission_groups=2) -> NO_MATCH
5. Document(allowed_groups=1,2,7) with Person(permission_groups=8) -> NO_MATCH
6. Document(allowed_groups=1,2,7) with Person(permission_groups=1,2,7) -> MATCH

If I do this:

```
person = Person.objects.get(pk=1)
Document.objects.filter(allowed_groups__in=person.permission_groups.all())
```

I would match on all of the above cases except 8 (not what I want)

There are many questions on stack overflow that are asking about exact matching i.e. match only on case 6 but not case 1.  (also not what I want)

So my question is how can I use django to do this? I've considered using SQL but surely there is a way to do with Django ORM. It doesn't seem like that much of a crazy requirement.

Note: I have a few other conditions (other types of groups and Document access levels) which I'ved turned into a complicated expression with chained filter/Q Objects, but I've got all that worked out except for this bit.

Also: I'm having a bit of trouble phrasing my question title, which might be why I can't find an answer. It doesn't need to be query set, it could just be a list of pks or some other method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55484433/16004568)

Solution:

```py
from django.db.models import Count, Q

person = Person.objects.get(pk=1)
permission_groups = set(person.permission_groups.all())
Document.objects.annotate(
    allowed_groups_count=Count('allowed_groups', filter=Q(allowed_groups__in=permission_groups))
).filter(
    allowed_groups_count__gt=0
)
```

And then its query will be something like this:

```sql
SELECT
  document.id,
  COUNT(document_allowed_groups.group_id) FILTER (
    WHERE
      document_allowed_groups.group_id IN (1, 2, 6, 7, 11, 15)
  ) AS allowed_groups_count
FROM
  document
  LEFT OUTER JOIN document_allowed_groups ON (
    document.id = document_allowed_groups.document_id
  )
GROUP BY
  document.id
HAVING
  COUNT(document_allowed_groups.group_id) FILTER (
    WHERE
      (
        document_allowed_groups.group_id IN (1, 2, 6, 7, 11, 15)
      )
  ) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Used the np.isin function from the numpy library. It returns boolean array when comparing two arrays. Description [here.](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html)

I applied values_list and flat=True to the objects to extract them into a list for comparison in numpy. I made a list generator aaa(list generator is many times faster than a loop) in which document is compared with the selected person, if all document values match, then all () returns True, then i.pk is written to the aaa list. Next, the document data is filtered by this list and passed to a dictionary to be displayed in the template.

**Replace bboard with the name of the folder where your templates are placed.**
I have this: templates/bboard which are in the application folder.

views.py

```
import numpy as np

def info(request):
    person = Person.objects.get(pk=1).permission_groups.all().values_list('id', flat=True)
    print(person)

    def my_func(x):
        document = Document.objects.get(pk=x).allowed_groups.all().values_list('id', flat=True)

        return document

    aaa = [i.pk for i in Document.objects.all() if np.isin(my_func(i.pk), person).all()]
    document = Document.objects.filter(pk__in=aaa)

    return render(request, 'bboard/templ.html', {'context': document})
```

templates

```
{% for a in context %}
<p>{{ a.id }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

**Update 26.10.2022**

```
import numpy as np

def info(request):
    person = Person.objects.get(pk=1).permission_groups.all().values_list('id', flat=True)

    def my_func(i):
        document = i.allowed_groups.all().values_list('id', flat=True)

        return document

    aaa = [i.pk for i in Document.objects.prefetch_related('allowed_groups').all() if np.isin(my_func(i), person).all()]
    document = Document.objects.filter(pk__in=aaa)

    return render(request, 'bboard/templ.html', {'context': document})
```

Comment: Thank you! I guess there are many ways to do it if it's going to involve pulling everything out of the database first then iterating over every row. I was wondering if it could be done at the filter/sql level. Would this just have one hit to the database? or is `Document.objects.get(pk=x).allowed_groups.all().values_list('id', flat=True)` going to make another query?

Comment: I think a `Document.objects.prefetch_related('allowed_groups').all()` will fix that

Comment: As far as I know, that the database is accessed at the time of accessing a specific record.? That is, in the my_func function, this happens when document is received. Changed the view a bit. It would be nice to see how using only django to get the same thing.